# Luke Lucene QueryParser Case Sensitivity

Tags: lucene, luke

In Luke, if I enter the search expression `docfile:Tomatoes.jpg*` the parsed query is `docfile:Tomatoes.jpg*`.  When the search expression is `docfile:Tomatoes.jpg`, (no asterisk *) the parsed query is `docfile:tomatoes.jpg` with a lowercase 't'.

1. Why?
2. How can I change this?

BTW, using org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`StandardAnalyzer` uses `LowerCaseFilter` which means it lowercases your queries and data. This is described in the Javadocs http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html.

If I remember correctly `WhitespaceAnalyzer` does not lowercase, but verify it suits your needs http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/WhitespaceAnalyzer.html.

Comment: StandardAnalyzer doesn't seem to be lowering the case of my data.  docfile:Tomatoes.jpg* returns the expected results, while docfile:Tomatoes.jpg returns 0.  docfile:Tomatoes.jpg, using WhitespaceAnalyzer or KeywordAnalyzer does return the expected results.  The data was indexed with StandardAnalyzer.  Not being too experienced with Lucene, I don't know if it's ok to use a different analyzer while searching or not.  Is this a common practice?

Comment: Are you certain the data is not lowercased in the index? Did you run it through an analyzer?

Comment: You usually should use the same analyzer your storing and searching.

Comment: It was indexed with StandardAnalyzer.

Comment: I am having the same issue, items are indexed with standard analyzer and lowercase queries do not return results but same case queries do return results

Comment: As said before, docs have to be indexed with the same analyzer you are pulling data out of it.

Answer (score 1):

For Lucene 5.3.0 the problem was solved by using the SimpleAnalyzer.

Example:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.SimpleAnalyzer();
```

Finally, use the same analyzer for building the index and searching.